# Access C++ class from Haxe using extern

Tags: c++, haxe

I want to access C++ code from a Haxe program. I am trying to use extern class but am facing some issues. I am trying to compile using haxe -main Cpp_Extern -cpp Cpp_Extern.

My Haxe code:

```
@:include("./Rectangle.cpp")
@:extern("Rectangle*")
extern class Rectangle
{
    @:native("set_values") public function set_values(w : Int, h : Int) : Void;
    @:native("new Rectangle") public static function create() : Rectangle;
}

class Cpp_Extern
{
    public static function main()
    {
        Rectangle.set_values(10,20);
    }
}
```

Code for C++

```
#include <iostream>

class Rectangle
{
  public:
  void set_values (int x, int y) 
    {
        std::cout << "x = " << x << "\n";
        std::cout << "y = " << y << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Rectangle one;
    return 0;
}
```

The error is

```
C:\Users\ila5\Desktop\CPP\Cpp_Extern>haxe -main Cpp_Extern -cpp Cpp_Extern
haxelib run hxcpp Build.xml haxe -Dhaxe3="1" -Dhaxe_ver="3.201" -Dhxcpp_api_level="321" -I"C:\\HaxeToolkit\\haxe\\extraLibs/" -I"" -I"C:\\HaxeToolkit\\haxe\\std/cpp/_std/" -I"C:\\HaxeToolkit\\haxe\\std/"
cl.exe -Iinclude -nologo -O2 /WX- /fp:precise -DHX_WINDOWS -D_USING_V140_SDK71_ -GR -FS -Oy- -c -EHs -GS- -arch:SSE -IC:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/hxcpp/3,2,205/include -DHXCPP_VISIT_ALLOCS -DHXCPP_API_LEVEL=321 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_ALLOW_MSC_VER_MISMATCH -D_ALLOW_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL_MISMATCH -wd4996 -MT ./src/Cpp_Extern.cpp -FoC:/Users/ila5/Desktop/CPP/Cpp_Extern/Cpp_Extern/obj/msvc19xp/2c1b12bd_Cpp_Extern.obj
Cpp_Extern.cpp
./src/Cpp_Extern.cpp(30): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'Rectangle *' to 'Rectangle'
./src/Cpp_Extern.cpp(30): note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
./src/Cpp_Extern.cpp(34): error C2819: type 'Rectangle' does not have an overloaded member 'operator ->'
C:/Users/ila5/Desktop/CPP/Cpp_Extern/Rectangle.cpp(4): note: see declaration of 'Rectangle'
./src/Cpp_Extern.cpp(34): note: did you intend to use '.' instead?
./src/Cpp_Extern.cpp(34): error C2232: '->Rectangle::set_values': left operand has 'class' type, use '.'

Error: Build failed
```

Comment: What errors the compiler is giving you ?

Comment: @AxelGuilmin I've included the error as an edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add the `@:include` and `@:extern` metadata to your extern class so that hxcpp can point to the correct file and resolve when compiling.

The `@:include` meta tag allows you to point to a file, which is placed above your extern class definition. The file needs to be relative to your build output directory.

The `@:extern` meta tag tells hxcpp to resolve the class definition to the name of the class you expect to see in C++. So, if you're creating a pointer, the class would be instantiated using the `new` keyword, and the extern definition would be the following:

```
@:include("includes/Rectangle.cpp")
@:extern("Rectangle*")
extern class Rectangle
{
    @:native("set_values") public function set_values(w : Int, h : Int) : Void;
    @:native("new Rectangle") public static function create() : Rectangle;
}
```

You cannot use the `new` function definition with an extern class, because it is not a regular Haxe class. Instead you need to make a static function that will do the instantion, which will return the extern class type into Haxe context, allowing you to then access its member variables.

If you have problems including a file for hxcpp to find, what you can do is use an XML file, which you would use to tell hxcpp what folders to find.

On Windows, you can use the `<files id="haxe">` tag followed by the contents `<compilerflag value="-I/../includes/" />`. Of course, close this tag off and make sure that the includes folder is in the root of your project.

This will generate an additional compiler flag telling the Haxe Compiler to look in an additional folder for C++ source files to include. You can then remove the `include/` prefix in your `@:include` just before your extern class definition.

To then tell hxcpp to use the XML file, you need to use the `@:buildXml` meta tag above the main entry point, which should contain the following: `<include name="${haxelib:myCustomRepo}/../Build.xml" />` Again, this needs to be relative to the root of your project.

In the above XML example, I use the `${haxelib:myCustomRepo}` which tells Haxe to look for the path of the given haxelib. You can set a haxelib repository development directory using the command: `haxelib dev myCustomRepo ./` that may help you in this situation. This will entirely depend on if you use that route.

You don't have to use XML files, but it's recommended for larger projects, especially when building across platforms and targets.

I also noticed you are missing a constructor in your C++ code, so don't forget to put that in. In addition, your main entry point code should now look like this:

```
@:buildXml('<include name="${haxelib:myCustomRepo}/../Build.xml" />') //only if you are using XML
class Main {
    public static function main() {
        var rect = Rectangle.create();
        rect.set_values(10, 20);
    }
}
```

There are two ways you can instantiate objects in C++. You can use the `new` keyword in which case the returning object should be a pointer to the type. So `new Rectangle()` will return a `Rectangle*` in C++. If you use `Rectangle.create()` in Haxe, and assign it to a variable, that's what you effectively get.

You can also instantiate, or rather declare, using `Rectangle rect;` in C++. This is accessed like a struct, so instead of using `->` to access members, you use a full stop '.'

For this to work in Haxe, you need to add the `@:structAccess` metadata on the extern. In addition, you need to change the `@:native` from being `@:native("Rectangle*")` to `@:native("Rectangle&")`. This makes sure that the initial variable will always be used as a reference.

The `&` means to use a variable **as** a reference, unlike pointers, which **is** a reference.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Ive made some edits to my question but Im still facing with issues.

Comment: Okay, so `cout` is part of the `std` namespace, so you need to use `std::cout`. As for the `set_values` not found, I believe that's because you're missing a semi-colon at the end of the definition in the C++ source file. I could be wrong, though. It may be that when you resolve the first error, other errors will be auto-resolved, that is sometimes the case.

Also, under your Rectangle class in C++, create a constructor:
`public: Rectangle();` That will allow for creating the object as required.

Comment: Thanks very much. The cout error has been resolved but Im not able to resolve the set_values error.

Comment: You didn't instantiate the object in Haxe. That's why you have the `create` function. Your code should be this:

`var rect = Rectangle.create(); rect.set_values(10, 20);` `set_values` shouldn't be a static function.

Comment: Oh shoot. Sorry about that. Still having issues though. Made an edit

Comment: See the following [paste](http://pastebin.com/060ij3Ya), I've provided two examples. One using the static method, the other without, which is what I recommend. Depends how you wish to use it.

Comment: The static method worked, thanks for that.
I'm facing the same error with the non-static method.

Comment: Is it because I'm calling a non-static function from the static main method in haxe?

Comment: I've updated my answer discussing the differences between pointers and addresses, and how you use them in the context of Haxe.

Your main entry point in Haxe has got nothing to do with it. It's just like any OOP language, you need to instantiate an object first before you can access any of its members.

Answer (score 0):

https://haxe.io/roundups/wwx/c++-magic/

```js
// Avoids generating dynamic accessors.
@:unreflective
// Marks an extern class as using struct access(".") not pointer("->").
@:structAccess
@:include("string")
@:native("std::string")
extern class StdString {
 @:native("new std::string")
 public static function create(inString:String):cpp:Pointer<StdString>;
 public function size():Int;
 public function find(str:String):Int;
}

class Main {
 
 public static function main() {
  var std = StdString.create("my std::string");
  trace( std.value.size() );
  std.destroy();
 }
}
```